# VB.NET and LINQ - Group by in a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, group-by

I have a DataTable in VB.NET of this type:

```
"Yr","Mnth","Period","Amount"
2016, 1, 2016-01, 550.36
2016, 1, 2016-01, 9000.79
2015, 12, 2015-12, 10000.30
2015, 12, 2015-12, 20
```

What I want to do is to aggregate this data using LINQ like I would in SQL language:

```
SELECT Yr, Mnth, Period, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
GROUP BY Yr, Mnth, Period;
```

I have tried to use LINQ in VB.NET but haven't been able to get it right.
Can someone give me some insight?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you _have_ to group the data from the `DataTable` or can you group the source data instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim Amounts As New DataTable 'Your code to load actual DataTable here
Dim amountGrpByDates = From row In Amounts
                       Group row By dateGroup = New With {
                                                    Key .Yr = row.Field(Of Integer)("Yr"),
                                                    Key .Mnth = row.Field(Of Integer)("Mnth"),
                                                    Key .Period = row.Field(Of String)("Period")
                                               } Into Group
                       Select New With {
                                  Key .Dates = dateGroup,
                                      .SumAmount = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("Amount"))}
```

I assumed `Yr` and `Mnth` to be of type Integer, `Period`  String and `Amount` Decimal. 
Change the types if they differ from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the C# code.

```
public static class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("year", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("month", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("period", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(decimal));

            var row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            row["year"] = "2015";
            row["month"] = "Jan";
            row["period"] = "Period1";
            row["amount"] = 100;


            row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            row["year"] = "2015";
            row["month"] = "Jan";
            row["period"] = "Period1";
            row["amount"] = 50;

            row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            row["year"] = "2016";
            row["month"] = "Fed";
            row["period"] = "Period2";
            row["amount"] = 5.55;


            var result = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                          group r by new
                          {
                              Year = r.Field<string>("year"),
                              Month = r.Field<string>("month"),
                              Period = r.Field<string>("period"),
                          } into grp
                          select new {
                              grp.Key,
                              total = grp.Sum(p=> p.Field<decimal>("amount"))
                          });


            foreach(var grp in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", grp.Key.Year, grp.Key.Month, grp.Key.Period, grp.total); 
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The poster asked for vb.net, not C#