# LINQ query to get distinct and count in VB.NET using Winforms

Tags: linq, datatable, count, distinct

I have a datatable with data, and some queries that I am working on.

I am using the `.CopyToDataTable` function to insert the rows into a new datatable.
I am able to get the distinct values as I copy the rows to a datatable using `.CopyToDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC")`, but I think there is a better way to do this.

This is my query now - it gets me 3 columns and their distinct values, and copies the results to a datatable, and then I bind that datatable to a datagridview.  I should note that there are about 20 columns in the datatable DT1, and I need only certain columns in the resulting datatable.

```
        Dim retRows = From myRows In DT1.AsEnumerable()
                  Where myRows.Field(Of String)("CORIENTATION").Trim.Equals("FRONT")
                  Select myRows

    DT3 = retRows.CopyToDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "CPA_DEF", "CCH_DEF", "CORIENTATION")
    DataGridView4.DataSource = DT3
```

Can someone show me how I can show another column with a count of distinct rows in it, using only LINQ to get there (from the existing data in the datatable)?

I guess I am looking for the T-SQL equivilant to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COUNT(*) AS COUNT1 FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
```

I need to do this in LINQ and I am a little lost.  I just started with LINQ.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not looking for something like, "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COUNT(*) AS COUNT1 FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3"?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot the grouping.  I edited the question.   Would the same apply in the LINQ query?

Comment: I would look at the Group By Into LINQ syntax for VB.Net.  You should be able to return a group key and total count for each.

Comment: I have been trying for hours - I think I need to see an example that uses a datatable to get the data, and puts those results back into a datatable.

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699938/vb-net-and-linq-group-by-in-a-datatable

Comment: I assume you mean the LINQ equivalent to the T-SQL :) Why do you feel you need `DISTINCT` if you are already doing `GROUP BY` the same columns?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to put the answer into a `DataTable`? LINQ and `DataTable`s don't mix easily because you can't create anonymous rows easily. You will have to pre-create a `DataTable` containing the columns you want and create a custom `CopyToDataTable`. Are your datagridview users allowed to edit the data?